# SharePoint Designer 2013 - How do I hide some fields on 'NewForm.aspx' so that they only show on 'EditForm.aspx'?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath

I can only open 'NewForm.aspx' in Advanced edit mode, not safe mode so struggling with finding the 'Fields' that I want to hide.
Can anyone advise on how I can find these 'Fields' or perhaps a different way in which I can hide them?
The form I have created is an InfoPath 2013 form, so if there is a way I can do this via InfoPath, that would be fantastic as well.

Thank you for your assistance -

Kind regards,

Janice

Comment: Are you OK with PowerSehll code?

Comment: Hi Nadeem, I have PowerShell installed but have not used it as of yet - I am confident that I can pick it up fast, so if you have any steps and coding, I would be very grateful for your input on this. Thank you, Janice :)

Comment: This would be very easy if you create three different forms for the same list.. do you have multiple views for your Infopath form?

Comment: Hi user19952,I have now created multiple views for the InfoPath form, I will watch a youtube tutorial to assist me in making these views available in the SharePoint List

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://yoursitename"
$list = $web.List["YourListName"]
$field1 = $list.Fields["YourFirstFieldInternalName"]
$field2 = $list.Fields["YourSecondFieldInternalName"]
$field1.ShowInNewForm = $false
$field1.Update()
$field2.ShowInNewForm = $false
$field2.Update()
```

Copy it and change the variables per your requirement. Then open SharePoint PowerShell (Run as Administrator) Paste the code and hit enter.